# Mozilla security error: Failed to load worker script

Tags: javascript, pdf, mozilla, pdf.js

I am trying to implement a `flip book` application using [pdf-flipbook master](https://github.com/erayakartuna/pdf-flipbook). In localhost its working fine in both `mozilla` and `chrome`. But when I try to deploy in physical server I am getting this error in `mozilla` and pdf not loading. In `chrome` its working fine.

```
Mozilla security error: Failed to load worker script https://s3-xxxxxxxxxx/static/js/flip-book/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

localhost viewer.js code

```
PDFJS.imageResourcesPath = 'images/';
PDFJS.workerSrc = '/static/js/flip-book/build/pdf.worker.js';
PDFJS.cMapUrl = 'pdfjs/cmaps/';
PDFJS.cMapPacked = true;
```

S3 bucket viewer.js code

```
PDFJS.imageResourcesPath = 'images/';
PDFJS.workerSrc = 'https://s3-ap-xxxxxxx/static/js/flip-book/build/pdf.worker.js';
PDFJS.cMapUrl = 'pdfjs/cmaps/';
PDFJS.cMapPacked = true;
```

Can someone help me to find what is going on here.I am new to javascript

Comment: same problem here ! HAve you found any solution ?

Comment: I did not got the actual solution for this. What I did is to kept all the js files in my instance instead of s3 bucket. The problem is solved now for temporarily. Now it's working on every browser.

Comment: On my side, I use firefox cdn as source.